# Is it possible to teach the keepalive agent to overcome TLS/SSL certificate warnings?

Tags: security, urls, certificate

We have an internal environment where the TLS/SSL certificate on tenants is not playing well with some requests. This is not a huge issue for clients who can add a one time trust for the certificate, but it causes some issues with the keepalive.aspx agent trying to poll the tenants root URL.

So my question is if anybody knows of a way to configure the keepalive agent in a way, that it can try to overcome certificate warnings / validations?

Here's an excerpt from our log file:

```
Exception in UrlAgent (url: /sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx)
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
Source: System
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   at Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ExecuteWebPage(String url, NameValueCollection headers)
   at Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent.Run()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException
Message: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

And yes, I do know that the proper way would be to fix the certificate :) I am actually more interested in a quick fix as due the affected environment is basically end of life and the next step would be a general overhaul anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override UrlAgent that is used to make `keepalive.aspx` call. And disable certificate validation:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
              ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

It is configured in Sitecore.config:

```
<agent type="YourNamespace.YourUrlAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:00">
  <param desc="url">/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx</param>
  <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
</agent>
```

You can have your own one class, where SSL errors are ignored

```
public class YourUrlAgent
{
    private readonly string _url;

    private bool _logActivity = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the <see cref="T:Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent" /> logs the activity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if the <see cref="T:Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent" /> logs the  activity; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool LogActivity
    {
        get
        {
            return this._logActivity;
        }
        set
        {
            this._logActivity = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL.</param>
    public UrlAgent(string url)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(url, "url");
        this._url = url;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs the pipeline.
    /// </summary>
    public void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            //Trust all certificates 
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
              ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
            string fullUrl = WebUtil.GetFullUrl(this._url);
            this.LogInfo("Scheduling.UrlAgent started. Url: " + fullUrl);
            string text = WebUtil.ExecuteWebPage(fullUrl);
            this.LogInfo("Scheduling.UrlAgent done (received: " + text.Length + " bytes)");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error("Exception in UrlAgent (url: " + this._url + ")", exception, this);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs the info.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    private void LogInfo(string message)
    {
        if (!this.LogActivity)
        {
            return;
        }
        Log.Info(message, this);
    }
}
```

P.S. As your wrote, it is not cool to do it.

P.S.2: If you have calls from your website to other URLs except `keepalive.aspx`, e.g. some API then it is much more better and secure to skip server certification check only for one request.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for sharing this approach!